# Posting non-Imgur hosted images in Community Promotion Ads?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

Recently, I noticed [this ad](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5504/community-promotion-ads-2013/7048#7048) on Ask Ubuntu Meta:

[image]

Interestingly, this ad is not hosted on Imgur. Instead, the image URL is:

> http://hostmar.co/au/edge/

The rules at the top of the page state that the image:

> "Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)"

According to the comments, at least one user has even seen it show up in the ad rotation.

Now, I'm not against this particular image being shown on the site. It is highly relevant and having the image automatically update is convenient. However, it would be great if the policy on this could be clarified:

**Under what circumstances are exceptions to the Imgur hosting requirement granted?**

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've seen dynamic content in ads hosted outside of imgur before; the system doesn't check (except the spam checks, maybe)

Comment: Surely it's not feasible to expect an external ad service (however well behaved it may or may not be re appropriate content, as much discussed) to comply with such a requirement?

Comment: @Mandy this was about a community ad (the ones they ask us to suggest every year on per-site metas). Also, 6 years old post.

Comment: So it is! Wonder why it got resurrected.